# session variable changes unexpectedly on page load in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a problem with SESSIONs in wordpress. I have looked around but could not find any answer. A similar question has been asked in another post on stackaoverflow, but no answer yet.
I have followed this tutorial to build my own FORM:[build your own wordpress contact form in 5 minutes.](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/.)

### The problem

To make my form more secure, I decided to generate a session string, and store this string in a SESSION global array (to prevent form hijacking). I send this same string as hidden field when the form is posted. And than I compare this 2 values. However, it seems to me that when the form is submitted, the SESSION is not the same as the one i stored in the SESSION array before submission.

```
function myfunction() {    
    ob_start();            
    $errors = array();    

    //deliver_mail();     
    if(isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {         

        if( $_POST['formtoken1'] !== $_SESSION['formtoken1'] ) {                       
            $errors['token'] = '<div>The form submited is not valid.</div>'; 
            //debug
            echo $_SESSION['formtoken1'];//At this point, SESSION[formtoken1] should be same as the one we generated before FORM submit, but it is not!
        }

        if(empty($errors)) {            
            //No Errors! Send Email                        
        }   
    }    

    $_SESSION['formtoken1'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));    
    $_SESSION['formtoken1'] = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['formtoken1']);            

    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';    
    echo '<input type="text" name="formtoken1" id="formtoken1" value="'. (isset($_SESSION['formtoken1']) ? $_SESSION['formtoken1'] : '') . '" />';           

    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';

return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_contact_form', 'myfunction' );//Create shortcode
```

When this form is submitted, it always creates error because SESSION variable is not same as the POST variable. When I test this same code outside wordpress on my local xampp server, it works. I will be greatful if anyone can help me. I have also tried session_start() at top of script, but still the same problem.

Comment: I thought $_SESSION is super global in PHP and therefore I can use it inside a function without any local scope problems.

Comment: You should try storing the "session string"s in an associative array inside of $_SESSION that way they don't get overwritten. For simplicity call it issuedKeys. When a new "key" is issued, add it to the array with a value of true. When you check the key, check it with isset() and delete.

Comment: Add some kind of logging to see if your function is perhaps executed multiple times.

Comment: Side note, why are you running a condition to `$_SESSION['formtoken1']` if it just have been declared? It will always be set.  also htmlspecialchars transform only amper, quotes and less than and greated than signals. MD5 will never generate any of these characters.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials, I realized that the post title was displaying on top of the page. I was starting ob_start() inside myfunction(). So, title was outputting before SESSION was started. I changed the code as below, and it works for now. The only problem with this solution is that wordpress is calling ob_start() at every page load. it would be better if it worked inside the myfunction() because it would mean ob_start() is executed only when the short-code is called within a post. 
`

```
//Plugin Name: test form    

ob_start(); //put this outside the myfunction()          

if(!session_id() ) { 
    session_start();     
}

function myfunction() {    

    $errors = array();    

    //deliver_mail();     
    if(isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {         

        if( $_POST['formtoken1'] !== $_SESSION['formtoken1'] ) {                       
            $errors['token'] = '<div>The form submited is not valid.</div>'; 
            //debug
            echo $_SESSION['formtoken1'];//At this point, SESSION[formtoken1] should be same as the one we generated before FORM submit, but it is not!
        } 

        if(empty($errors)) {            
            //No Errors! Send Email             
        }   
    }    

    $_SESSION['formtoken1'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));    
    $_SESSION['formtoken1'] = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['formtoken1']);            

    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';    
    echo '<input type="text" name="formtoken1" id="formtoken1" value="'. (isset($_SESSION['formtoken1']) ? $_SESSION['formtoken1'] : '') . '" />';           
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';

    return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_contact_form', 'myfunction' );//Create shortcode`
```